# How to prefill django form Dynamically

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am trying to display a form in django and pre-filling it dynamically.
I want the user of my sample news gathering site to modify an entry.

I have my Manual Input form class

```
#forms.py
class ManualInputForm(forms.Form):
    source = forms.CharField(label="Source:", widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 97}))
    topic  = forms.CharField(label="Topic:", widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 97}))
    news   = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows":5, "cols":100}))
    link   = forms.CharField(label="Link (optional):", required = False, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 97}))
```

In the HTML I am going manually because I would like to pre-fill all fields with data coming in from the related function in `views.py`.

```
#html file
<form method="post" class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            {% for field in form  %}
                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ field.errors }}
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    <br>
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <p> </p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How do I do it? It's driving me crazy o.O
I would like to keep using django's forms because of its integrated error manager (not all fields are required but some are and I'd like for django to keep managing it).

Thank your for your suggestions!

EDIT:
as requested I'll post the views.py related function:

```py
#views.py
def editnews(response, id):
    form = ManualInputForm(response.POST or None)

    #tableToView is a dataframe retrieved by querying an external DB
    #data cannot be stored in django's buit in because of reasons ;-)

    #checking the dataframe is correct and it is:
    #IT IS MADE OF A SINGLE LINE
    
    print(tableToView)

    #THIS IS PROBABLY NOT THE WAY TO DO IT
    form.source = tableToView.loc[0, 'Source']
    form.topic  = tableToView.loc[0, 'Topic']
    form.news   = tableToView.loc[0, 'News']
    form.link   = tableToView.loc[0, 'Link']

    return render(response, 'manual/editnews.html', {"form":form})
```

In the image the text should be pre-filled.

[image]

Comment: I put in javascript as a tag because maybe it can be achieved with a lil' script. But I seriously don't know (I am new to this new "web" thing ;-)

Comment: Can you update your post with the relevant part of `views.py`, please?

Comment: Updated post as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
def editnews(response, id):
    data = {k.lower(): v for k, v in tableToView.loc[0].to_dict().items()}
    form = ManualInputForm(response.POST or None, initial=data)
    return render(response, 'manual/editnews.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: the fields are still empty in the html unfortunately

Comment: Take care of case: `source` is different of `Source`

Comment: @Wing. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: Spot on! I was milead by the fact that the label had a capital letter, while the actual variable was lowercase

Answer (score 1):

when you are declaring or rendering form in view and sending it to template. use initial argument and pass dictionary in it with key as name of field and value as the text which you want prefilled.

like this
context['form'] = NameofForm(initial={'Source':'mysite', 'Topic':'mytopic'})
return context

Update

```py
> def test_view(request, pk):   
>     template_name = 'form.html'
>     form = MyForm(initial={"test":"initialize with this value"})
>         if request.method == 'POST':
>             form = MyForm(request.POST)
>             if form.is_valid():
>                 form.save()
>                 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list-view'))
> 
>     return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: ok... and how do I fetch it from the HTML?

Comment: you won't need to. that's the beauty of it. however do remember declare initial in get method and not in post. See my initial answer's update

Comment: ok I am trying to test it... what is ```reverse('list-view')``` ?

Comment: Alright. It's name of url of list view. after submitting form i am redirecting user back to list view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#views.py
def editnews(response, id):
    data = {}
    data["source"] = tableToView.loc[0, 'Source']
    data["topic"] = tableToView.loc[0, 'Topic']
    data["news"] = tableToView.loc[0, 'News']
    data["link"] = tableToView.loc[0, 'Link']

    form = ManualInputForm(response.POST or None, initial=data)

    return render(response, 'manual/editnews.html', {"form":form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with jQuery if you're using one. You'll need to set the attribute of id to the form field.

jQuery code example:

`$('#topic').val("Prefilled text goes here");`